# How to remove this \xa0 from a string in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following string:

```
 word = u'Buffalo,\xa0IL\xa060625'
```

I don't want the "\xa0" in there.  How can I get rid of it?  The string I want is:

```
word = 'Buffalo, IL 06025
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove those?  Are there other codepoints you would also want removed from a string?  Why can't you just encode the string to the proper encoding and use the resulting string?

Comment: now that I am looking at the old question again after working as a programmer for the past 3+ years..I realize this is a rather a dumb question. I am surprised that this question got so many votes though :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know for sure that is the only character you don't want, you can `.replace` it:

```
>>> word.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
u'Buffalo, IL 60625'
```

If you need to handle all non-ascii characters, encoding and replacing bad characters might be a good start...:

```
>>> word.encode('ascii', 'replace')
'Buffalo,?IL?60625'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I think of the encoding approach.  Conceptually it's a little strange, because you're starting with a string and turning it into bytes.

Comment: @DSM: It kind of depends on _why_ the asker wants to do this in the first place. Some of the different I can think of someone wanting this involve needing ASCII bytes, others involve still needing Unicode, and others involve the problem not being a problem in the first place…

Answer (score 32):

The most robust way would be to use the [`unidecode`  module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) to convert all non-ASCII characters to their closest [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) equivalent automatically.

The character `\xa0` (not `\xa` as you stated) is a [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm), and the closest ASCII equivalent would of course be a regular space.

```
import unidecode
word = unidecode.unidecode(word)
```

Comment: OK, how exactly would one do use the `unidecode` module to do such a conversion?

Comment: @martineau I don't have `unidecode` installed on my PC so I was hesitant to give a concrete example, it seems simple enough based on the docs. But since you insisted...

Comment: +1, because I've found the unidecode module invaluable in getting around the fact that only some of my tools support unicode, even though it's rocket vs. mosquito here.

Comment: @DSM even though the question only involves the non-break space character specifically, I'm assuming they have other Unicode characters that they just haven't run into yet. Any other solution is just delaying the day of reckoning.

Answer (score 10):

You can easily use `unicodedata` to get rid of all of `\x...` characters.

```
from unicodedata import normalize
normalize('NFKD', word)
>>> 'Buffalo, IL 60625'
```

Answer (score 8):

There is no `\xa` there. If you try to put that into a string literal, you're going to get a syntax error if you're lucky, or it's going to swallow up the next attempted character if you're not, because `\x` sequences aways have to be followed by two hexadecimal digits.

What you have is `\xa0`, which is an escape sequence for the character [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm), aka "NO-BREAK SPACE".

I think you want to replace them with spaces, but whatever you want to do is pretty easy to write:

```
word.replace(u'\xa0', u' ') # replaced with space
word.replace(u'\xa0', u'0') # closest to what you were literally asking for
word.replace(u'\xa0', u'')  # removed completely
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for getting rid of non-ascii characters:

```
fixedword = word.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Comment: That will remove all the spaces, and leave the OP with the wrong result.