# BeautifulSoup: Can't convert NavigableString to string

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm starting to learn Python and I've decided to code a simple scraper. One problem I'm encountering is I cannot convert a NavigableString to a regular string.

Using BeautifulSoup4 and Python 3.5.1. Should I just bite the bullet and go to an earlier version of Python and BeautifulSoup? Or is there a way 
I can code my own function to cast a NavigableString to a regular unicode string?

```
for tag in soup.find_all("span"):
    for child in tag.children:
        if "name" in tag.string: #triggers error, can't compare string to NavigableString/bytes
            return child

    #things i've tried:
    #if "name" in str(tag.string)
    #if "name" in unicode(tag.string) #not in 3.5?
    #if "name" in strring(tag.string, "utf-8")
    #tried regex, didn't work. Again, doesn't like NavigableSTring type. 
    #... bunch of other stuff too!
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried to decode when I should have encoded:

```
str(child.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Can you provide the full worked example of what worked?  The snippet you provided does not make it clear what the solution is.  Where does your str(child.encode('utf-8')) snippet go in your `for` loops above?

Answer (score 8):

### For Python 3...

... the answer is merely `str(tag.string)`

**Other answers will fail.**

`unicode()` is not a built-in in Python 3.

`tag.string.encode('utf-8')` will convert the string to a byte string, which you don't want..

Comment: No idea why you were downvoted, not only did this work for me it was super easy and simple to just do `str(value)` since it is built in.

Comment: @Merritt, me either!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
unicode(tag.string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up to this question and got it solved best by the answer of Mark Ramson from [How to remove this \xa0 from a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068832/how-to-remove-this-xa0-from-a-string-in-python/26068879) with

```
import unidecode
word = unidecode.unidecode(tag.string)
```