# How to rename a Pandas DataFrame column if the name is an empty string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've imported an HTML table from [Basketball Reference](http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2016_games.html) using pandas, but I'm running into an annoyance trying to rename a couple of columns that have empty strings for their name.

Here's the code to pull the table:

```
tables = pd.read_html('http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2016_games.html')
games = tables[0]
```

The columns look like this:

```
Out[138]: 

Index([u'Date', u'Start (ET)', u'Visitor/Neutral', u'PTS', u'Home/Neutral',
       u'PTS.1', u' ', u' .1', u'Notes'],
       dtype='object')
```

Renaming everything except for the `u' '` and `u' .1'` columns is no issue, but I cannot find the right way to rename the empty ones using a label approach.

I tried this by default (limited to renaming only a few columns here):

```
column_names = {'Date': 'date', ' ': 'box', ' .1': 'overtime'}
games.rename(columns = column_names)
```

but this leaves the `' '` and `' .1'` columns unchanged.

This method works:

```
column_names = {games.columns[6]: 'box', games.columns[7]: 'overtime'}
```

But is there any way to change these names without explicitly referencing the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me works add [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove trailing whitespaces, also is necessary change `dict` values (remove whitespaces):

```
column_names = {'Date': 'date', '': 'box', '.1': 'overtime'}
games.columns = games.columns.str.strip()
games = games.rename(columns = column_names)
print (games.columns)
Index(['date', 'Start (ET)', 'Visitor/Neutral', 'PTS', 'Home/Neutral', 'PTS.1',
       'box', 'overtime', 'Notes'],
      dtype='object')
```

Another solution is export column names to `list` and there is `\xa` ([NO-BREAK SPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069208/2901002)):

```
print (games.columns.tolist())
['Date', 'Start (ET)', 'Visitor/Neutral', 'PTS', 'Home/Neutral', 
 'PTS.1', '\xa0', '\xa0.1', 'Notes']


column_names = {'Date': 'date', '\xa0': 'box', '\xa0.1': 'overtime'}
games = games.rename(columns = column_names)
print (games.columns)
Index(['date', 'Start (ET)', 'Visitor/Neutral', 'PTS', 'Home/Neutral', 'PTS.1',
       'box', 'overtime', 'Notes'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: This does work, thank you!

Intuitively, is there a reason why `strip()` would work and allow renaming using `''`, whereas using `' '` in the original code wouldn't work?

Comment: There is no whitespace, but [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069208/2901002). But it can be removed `strip` also.

Comment: Makes sense, and I saw the edit/addition of converting to list to see the unicode - great to know, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a quick fix - Set the column names explicitly.

`df.columns = [u'Date', u'Start (ET)', u'Visitor/Neutral', u'PTS', u'Home/Neutral', u'PTS.1', u'Rename1', u'Rename2', u'Notes']`